# Coordinates of centroid

Tags: integration

Find the coordinates of the centroid of the region $R_1$ if the curve has equation $y=x(x-1)(x-2)$. Hence calculate without making further calculations judge the coordinates of the centroid of region $R_2$. ($Note$: $R_1$ is the area between 0 and 1 and $R_2$ is the area between 1 and 2 as shown on a sketch that I couldn't draw here)
I know the formulas $\bar x = \frac{1}{A} \int_a^b xf(x)dx$ and $\bar y = \frac{1}{A} \int_a^b \frac{(f(x))^2}{2}dx$ will get me that the coordinates for the centroid of $R_1$ and I know how i'll get the coordinates of the centroid of region $R_2$ after I have the coordinates for $R_1$. However i'm not entirely sure what to use for $a$ and $b$. I also have no idea why the formulas work or how they work or how they're derived. I have searched online and referred to numerous textbooks but am still more or less clueless. I would really appreciate if someone could explain the formulas

Answer (score 0):

> "In mathematics and physics, the centroid or geometric center of a
>   two-dimensional region is the arithmetic mean ("average") position of
>   all the points in the shape"

That's from wikipedia. There's various ways of thinking about it.

Suppose you have some function f(x). You can see this as the way points are distributed; i.e. f(x) is the distribution  of x. In that case, what is the mean of x?

Well, that's always the integral of x times the distribution. However, the distribution has to be normalised; that's what the "A" does; It's the normalisation constant.

A centroid is usually asked for some region. If it is not given, you can just assume that $[a,b]$ is the entire domain.

In your case, two distinct regions are given; $R_1:\{x: 0<x<1\}$ and $R_2:\{x: 1<x<2\}$.

So in this case, for region $R_1$ the $[a,b]$ are just $[0,1]$ and the region $R_2$ is $[1,2]$.

You are looking at the function bounded between the x-axis ($y=0$) and the function $f(x)$.

So your distribution is simply $f(x) = x (x-1) (x-2)$. Then, the x-centroid is the value of x times the (normalised) distribution:

$\overline{x} = \int_a^b x \frac{f(x)}{A} dx$

For the y-centroid, we need the value of $y$, which is $y(x) = f(x)$ times its distribution $f(x)$. The factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ is to avoid double counting. What I mean by that is that we have the product of two functions there; the value and the distribution. However, these can be the same; this would lead to double counting. To see this, consider $f(x)=2$. On $[0,1]$, this would give us $A = \int^1_0 2 dx = 2$ and $ \int^1_0 \frac{f(x)^2}{A} dx = \int^1_0 \frac{4}{2} dx = 2$. However, if you imagine the region, it is a block of constant distribution; so you would expect the centroid to be in the middle! That's because you double counted; you had both the "value" f(x) times the "distribution" f(x) and the distribution times the value. (If it makes it simpler: think of $f^2$ as $f \cdot g$; you had both f times g and g times f, which are the same).

Thus:
$\overline{y} = \int_a^b \frac{f(x)^2}{2A} dx$

Anyway, $f(x) = x (x-1) (x-2) = x(x^2 - 2x -x + 2) = x^3 - 3x^2 + 2x$ with primitive $F(x) = \frac{x^4}{4} - x^3 + x^2$.

We find:

$\overline{x}^\text{R1} = \frac{\int^1_0  x^4 - 3x^3 + 2x^2 dx}{F(1)-F(0)}$

$\overline{x}^\text{R2} = \frac{\int^2_1  x^4 - 3x^3 + 2x^2 dx}{F(2)-F(1)}$

$\overline{y}^\text{R1} = \frac{\int^1_0  (x^3 - 3x^2 + 2x)^2 dx}{2F(1)-2F(0)}$

$\overline{y}^\text{R2} = \frac{\int^2_1  (x^3 - 3x^2 + 2x)^2 dx}{2F(2)-2F(1)}$

I hope that sums things up.

Comment: why is the mean value of $x$  the integral of x times the distribution?

Comment: Suppose you have some chance event. You have, say, $\frac{4}{12}$ for a value 2, $\frac{3}{12}$ for a value 3 and $\frac{5}{12}$ for a value 5. What's the mean/expectation/average? Evidently, it's  $(4*2+3*3+5*5)/12 = 42/12$, which is $\sum^3_{n=1} P(X=x_n) x_n$ where $x_n = 2, 3, 5$. For continuous chance distributions, it's similar; Consider the riemann's sum as a way of seeing the discrete chance distribution. It follows that the "discrete chance" is $f(x)dx$ and the value is $x$; so the average/mean/expectation is $\int^b_a \quad x \cdot f(x)dx$.

Comment: I asked my teacher and he told me the formula is derived by taking moments. However he didn't explain how because he said it's not part of the syllabus I am studying. Could you explain the formula using moments?

Comment: The question you should ask is: What is a moment? If you consider the wikipedia page;http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(physics), you see the moment as the integral of some quantity Q is $\int r^n dq$, for some power $n$. Now, the example I gave you is the first moment. In terms of physics, you're asked to calculate the first moment of the quantity Q with dQ = f(x) dx. I hope this helps. Also, tell your teacher that it is imperative for your understanding and that he should either explain it to you, or refer you to someone who can.